# How to apply Pull Request locally?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-merge, pull-request

I would like to understand how to apply pull request on my local repo.

I have the following branches: master, production and the feature branch of the feature I'm currently working on.

Suppose I finished coding my feature, then I go on GitHub open a PullRequest, maybe discuss/ review my code, before it goes into production.

The next step would be to merge that feature branch into production (aka closing the PullRequest).

How do I apply these changes on my local repo?
Do I have to merge my local feature branch manually into my local production branch or should I just pull the server production branch and delete my local feature branch?

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: this might offer further insights https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally

Comment: also, you might want to consider switching to fossil-scm for a file versioning system that makes much more sense in general! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have basically described the methods on how to do this. Generally, if You have already merged You Pull Request, then you can simply call `git pull` on Your production branch and this is generally the preferred option IMHO.

If You would like to test the feature branch locally before merging the PR then obviously You would need to call `git merge` and merge the local `feature-branch` into Your local `master`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "right way" since it mostly depends on you and your coworkers' workflow.

However yes typically, when your PR will be merged into `master`, if your policy is indeed (like in many places) to delete the now-obsolete feature branch, get on master and pull to update it, then delete your local feature

```
git checkout master
git pull
git branch -d feature-branch
```

Answer (score 1):

the steps to open a pull request are -
- You first push your feature branch to remote and then you create it a PR (pull request) selecting that as the source and the target will be production branch in your example.
- This means your feature branch (as in your local git repo) is already in sync with the one in remote
- Once you merge the PR; Github will merge your feature branch into the production branch.

To update the local git repo; switch to production branch and do a pull from remote -

```
git checkout <production branch>
git pull origin <production branch>
```

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer! One more question what happens to the feature branch in my local repo?

Comment: It will stay there unless you will specifically delete it. If you want to delete it locally use - "git branch -d <branch>" if you want it to delete from remote as well - "git push remote --delete <branch>"

Comment: please accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a concrete example of the git command to do this (in one, albeit typical, scenario).  From the [Github help](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally)

In your local repo, check out whichever branch you want to apply the remote PR to.  Let's say that's local branch `a`

```
cd /me/src/my-repo
git checkout a
```

Fetch the PR from the Github *and* merge it into a *new* branch.  This creates the new branch in your local repo, but does *not* check it out (yet).  Let's say it's PR `#1234` and you want to create new branch `b`
If you work with the github repo a lot, you probably already have a remote defined for it, such as 'upstream'.  If not, you can specify the full URL instead:

```
git fetch upstream pull/1234/head:b
```

or

```
git fetch https://github.com/<them>/<their-repo> pull/1234/head:b
```

Finally, at your leisure, check out the new branch and play with it.

```
git checkout b
```